# Hadwiger's proof for Borsuk conjecture for smooth and convex bodies.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, combinatorial-geometry

I heard that Borsuk conjecture is true in the smooth and convex case but I couldn't find the proof. Wikipedia gives a reference to an article by Hadwiger but it is in german.
Do you have a reference for the proof in english?

Thanks a lot.